# Codename One MediaManager issue on iOS11

Tags: ios, codenameone, ios11

My app uses MediaManager for playing streaming audio MP3.

```
m = MediaManager.createMedia('http://...URL to media...', false); 
m.play();
```

Recently I changed the media URL to use **https** instead of *http* per iOS11 requirements.

The media playback works just fine in CodeNameOne iPhone Simulator, which comes with the Netbeans plugin. However, on an actual iOS device, the media playback is choppy and takes short pauses at regular intervals. It plays audio for 0.5 seconds (more or less) then pauses for 0.1 seconds (more of less) as if it has to do some computation (such as decryption) every so often at regular intervals.

Has this problem been reported before? Is there a known solution?

Comment: Please edit your post instead of posting comments

Answer (score 0):

We use the native media playback widget so we have limited control over this. I think you might need to use a lower quality/resolution/size file to prevent choppiness in playback on a real device.